# (Micro)Python UART response ends with "#Eg[" or adds characters

Tags: python, micropython, rp2040

```py
from machine import Pin, I2C, UART
import utime
from ustruct import unpack
import time

checkCardCmd = bytes([0xff,0x00,0x01,0x83,0x84])
getFirmwareVersionCmd = bytes([0xff,0x00,0x01,0x81,0x82])

uart = UART(1, baudrate=19200, bits=8, parity=None, stop=1)

while True:
    # Check if card is present
    uart.write(checkCardCmd)
    val = uart.read()
    print(val)

    utime.sleep_ms(250)
```

When a card is presented on the NFC reader I get this back from `val` `b'\xff\x00\x06\x83\x02\x01#Eg['`

This is the reply to the `checkCardCmd`. I have no clue why it ends with `#Eg[` also the reply for no card found comes back as `b'\xff\x00\x02\x83N\xd3'` notice the `N` character on the 4th byte, that should just be `x83`.

Baud Rate is correct and with similar code in NodeJS I get the proper response from UART without the extra `N` or `#Eg]`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your device is responding with raw binary bytes. Those are being stored in a string. Where a byte corresponds to a printable ASCII character, that character is being printed. Where the byte does not correspond to an ASCII character, or corresponds to an unprintable one, the `\xnn` syntax is used. `#` is simply the same as `\x23`, i.e. `0x23`. `N` in ASCII is `0x4E`. `#Eg[` is the byte sequence `0x23 0x45 0x67 0x5B`

Comment: @canton7 Oh jesus I didn't even think of that. Thanks! Problem solved and I got the correct output from the reader now :-)